# some problems with Android Bitmap in Out of Memory

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, out-of-memory

I creat a ViewFlipper to show images form Internet in a singal activity. When fling, set image to an imageView then  add it to the viewflipper.
But the question is that OOM always occures  after showed about 20 images. 
I had did some clean jobs to sovle it and it didn't work!
Here is the code.

```
public class ImageCache {

static private ImageCache cache;
private Hashtable<Integer, MySoftRef> hashRefs;
private ReferenceQueue<Bitmap> q;

private class MySoftRef extends SoftReference<Bitmap> {
    private Integer _key = 0;

    public MySoftRef(Bitmap bmp, ReferenceQueue<Bitmap> q, int key) {
        super(bmp, q);
        _key = key;
    }
}


public ImageCache() {
    hashRefs = new Hashtable<Integer, MySoftRef>();
    q = new ReferenceQueue<Bitmap>();
}

public static ImageCache getInstance() {
    if (cache == null) {
        cache = new ImageCache();
    }
    return cache;
}

private void addCacheBitmap(Bitmap bmp, Integer key) {
    cleanCache();
    MySoftRef ref = new MySoftRef(bmp, q, key);
    hashRefs.put(key, ref);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(int resId) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (hashRefs.containsKey(resId)) {
        MySoftRef ref = (MySoftRef) hashRefs.get(resId);
        bmp = (Bitmap) ref.get();
    }

    if (bmp == null) {
        URL imgUrl = null;
        try {
            imgUrl = new URL("http:/example/images/" + resId
                    + ".jpg");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmp  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            is.close();
            addCacheBitmap(bmp, resId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return bmp;
}

private void cleanCache() {
    MySoftRef ref = null;
    while ((ref = (MySoftRef) q.poll()) != null) {
        hashRefs.remove(ref._key);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    cleanCache();
    hashRefs.clear();
    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();
}
```

and here is the loadimage code.

```
public void LoadImage(int n){
    iv = new ImageView(this);
    imageCache = new ImageCache();
    Bitmap bm = imageCache.getBitmap(n);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    viewFlipper.addView(iv, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

Comment: Check this link ... http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Yup, worked for me to: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way to free the memory allocated with a Bitmap is [`recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29). You should [`removeView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) that are not in the range `[current - 1; current + 1]`, then `recycle` the Bitmap you allocated yourself. All that code seems an overkill to me, and also it's not a good idea to invoke the GC. You may save the contents of the InputStream on the permanet storage, so you won't have the network overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should only load and keep in cache the 3 images that you need :

- The previous image
- The current one
- The next one

Just free the memory of the others. Use the [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) fonction for that.
You can even keep 5 images if you want. but there is no need to keep them all.

If you want you application to be reactive, you can keep thumbnails in memory, display it, and only load the full image if you stay on the image more than x seconds.

Here is the code to create a smaller image and manage your list of bitmaps

```
Options mThumbOpts = new Options();
mThumbOpts.inSampleSize = 4;

/** The fonction to get a Bitmap from the list */
private Bitmap getBitmap(int id) {
    // TODO recycle previous/next bitmaps here (id -2 and id +2 if they exist)

    // Reload the image if necessary
    if (bitmapList[id] == null || bitmapList[id].isRecycled()) {
        bitmapList[id] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, mThumbOpts);
    }
    return bitmapList[id];
}
```

[inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.
Use a power of 2 for it to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you do not use singleton nature of your `ImageCache` class, you create new `ImageCache` instance every time `LoadImage(int n)` is called:

```
imageCache = new ImageCache();
Bitmap bm = imageCache.getBitmap(n);
```

Which is really strange. Use instead:

```
imageCache = ImageCache.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I've noticed this problem.